# Is it possible to create partial stashes with specific message/ name for the changes in the current branch?

Tags: git

My solution has multiple projects. My current changes are changes made to two different projects in the solution.

When I try the stash option in SourceTree it creates a single stash for the entire changes and I am able to give custom message/name  for the stash.

When I try [Partial stashes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash#partial-stashes) it helps me achieve what I want, but I am not able to give meaningful messages to the stash. It gives messages like the image below.

[image]

Is there a better away I can create multiple stashes for my current changes with meaningful messages/names?

Comment: For me, you'd better create a branch and a commit for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git stash` accepts `-m message` as an option ; when combined with `-p`, you would have to know the message before actually creating the stash :

```
git stash -m "I definitely know what I am about to do" -p
```

---

Note that you can also create regular commits, on a throwaway branch if you want :

```
git checkout -b wip/split_work
git add -p
git commit
git add -p
git commit
...
```

You can then :

- see the list of small commits you created : `git log --oneline wip/split_work`
- apply any individual commit : `git cherry-pick <sha>`